# Golang exec.Command() bash command not working

Tags: bash, go

I want to run the following bash command using golang's exec.Command()

```
ls > sample.txt
```

For this I write

```
_,err:=exec.Command("ls",">","sample.txt").Output()
```

But this doesn't seem to work. I know I can write to a file by using

```
exec.Command().StdoutPipe()
```

But I want to write sepcifically in that manner. Any idea how I can do it in golang?

Comment: If it's a bash command, you need bash to execute it. `ls` can't use `>` as an argument.

Comment: anyway I can do using channels in go?

Comment: I'm not sure what channels have to do with executing a command. You either need to execute a shell, or write the output yourself.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the docs:

> Unlike the "system" library call from C and other languages, the os/exec package intentionally does not invoke the system shell and does not expand any glob patterns or handle other expansions, pipelines, or redirections typically done by shells. The package behaves more like C's "exec" family of functions. To expand glob patterns, either call the shell directly, taking care to escape any dangerous input, or use the path/filepath package's Glob function. To expand environment variables, use package os's ExpandEnv.

With that in hand, my best guess to what you're trying to do is running bash and passing your command as an argument to it:

```
out, err := exec.Command("bash", "-c", cmd)
```